# Prevent git-bash to open in new terminal

Tags: windows, bash, git, visual-studio-code

I am running a sh script in VSCode, using Windows environment. When i run the .sh script from the internal VSCode terminal, it opens a new window from git-bash.

The problem is that inside the .sh there is some Docker commands that aren't recognized inside the git terminal, only outside, like running in integrated console from VSCode, in PowerShell.

How do I prevent to open this windows and allow the execution of these scripts inside the integrated VSCode console?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.